# preg match between two strings

Tags: php, regex

I need help with this preg match. I tried this from other post but did not get the result. So finally posting it.

I am trying to extract `z,a,b` from first and `a` from second example.

1) Write a function operations with parameter **z,a,b** and returns b.

2) write a function factorial with parameter **a**.

This is what I tried so far:

```
 preg_match_all('/\parameter(.*?)\and?/', $question, $match);
          $questionVars = $match[1];
          print $questionVars;
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm a little unclear. What is an example value of $question and $match, and what would you expect the output of $questionVars to be?

Comment: Try [`parameter \K[a-z,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/a93pS5/1)

Comment: Probably, you are after [`preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^),|\bparameter\s+)\K\w+~', $s, $matches)`](https://regex101.com/r/H59TPB/2)

Comment: I don't know if the individual letters would tell you anything. If you want to be more validating, use something like `parameter ([a-z]+(?:,[a-z]+)*)`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution can be different depending on actual requirements.

If you need a string after `parameter` as a whole word that can consist of word and comma chars you may use

```
preg_match('~\bparameter\s+\K\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*~', $s, $m)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VpGr21/2). The `\bparameter\s+`  matches a word boundary, `parameter` and 1+ whitespace chars, and all this text is omitted with the help of `\K`, the match reset operator. `\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*` matches and returns the 1+ word chars followed with 0+ repetitions of a comma enclosed with optional whitespace chars and again 1+ word chars.

If you plan to get those comma-separated chunks separately, use

```
preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|\bparameter\s+)\K\w+~', $s, $m)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H59TPB/3). Here, `(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\bparameter\s+)` will either match the whole word `parameter` with 1+ whitespace after (`\bparameter\s+`, as in the previous solution) or the end of the previous successful match with `,` enclosed with optional whitespace chars (`\G(?!^)\s*,\s*`). The `\K` will omit the text matched so far and `\w+` will grab the value. You may replace with `[^,]*` to grab 0+ chars other than a comma.

Comment: Thank you Everyone!! I was able to do it   with this. $result = preg_split('/parameters /', $question);
          $result = $result[1];
          $quest = explode(' ', trim($result)); As long as I dont keep spaces in question variables it works fine.

Comment: Yeah I see. I will try them out today.